# Pagination is not working correctly there is this wierd looping

Tags: pagination

I am working with a developer who recently updated my site to 3.3.1 My site is http://www.pagesandprint.com
When I open the site and then select Shop from the menu drill down to a category page like 1980-1989. When I scroll to the bottom of the page the beginning of the next page starts and it shows the category header again and the next item which should technically be displayed on the top of the next page. I looked through reference material throughout the internet and I can't see how to fix this and neither can the developer I am using. Does anyone have any suggestions of what I need to correct to get the correct pagination ?

Thank You
-karen-

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen this issue. without seeing the code that your developer wrote there isn't much to say here. Did he use a custom query to get the information from the database? Did he rewind the posts? Does he have the code for pagination in the template twice? which actually could be the case here. I have seen in wordpress templates where the code for the pagination is at the top of the page as well as the bottom of the page. If that is the case then all he would need to do is remove that code. The code would look something like this

```
<?php previous_posts_link("Last Page"); ?> | 
            <?php next_posts_link("Next Page"); ?>
```

Yours could be different.

Comment: Thanks for the response I am chatting with my developer to see if that helps